# Binding a list in @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, collections, spring-mvc

I'm sending some parameters from a form in this way:

```
myparam[0]     : 'myValue1'
myparam[1]     : 'myValue2'
myparam[2]     : 'myValue3'
otherParam     : 'otherValue'
anotherParam   : 'anotherValue' 
...
```

I know I can get all the params in the controller method by adding a parameter like

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params){
    ....
}
```

I want to bind the parameters myParam[] (not the other ones) to a list or array (anything that keeps the index order), so I've tried with a syntax like:

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam") List<String> myParams){
    ....
}
```

and

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam") String[] myParams){
    ....
}
```

but none of them are binding the myParams. Even when I add a value to the map it is not able to bind the params:

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam") Map<String, String> params){
    ....
}
```

Is there any syntax to bind some params to a list or array without having to create an object as @ModelAttribute with a list attribute in it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The code in `HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestParam` only ever gets the first value

Comment: (*Spring Boot*):  Is about `method = RequestMethod.GET` or `method = RequestMethod.POST`? If `.GET`   `@RequestParam List<String> groupVal` fulfilled from `?groupVal=kkk,ccc,mmm` successfully (*Spring Boot*)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Arrays in `@RequestParam` are used for binding several parameters of the same name:

```
myparam=myValue1&myparam=myValue2&myparam=myValue3
```

If you need to bind `@ModelAttribute`-style indexed parameters, I guess you need `@ModelAttribute` anyway.

Comment: there may be problems with the order (which is very important to keep in my case) because I send the parameters by serializing a form and sending i with ajax. I'll use the "traditional" @ModelAttribute way.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to construct a URI with this sort mapping with UriTemplate, or some other means? (for a client of this sort of resource).

Comment: Answering my own question, it apears the spring UriTemplate doesn't support RFC6570, use the damnhandy implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153036/how-to-send-array-with-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 124):

Or you could just do it that way:

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam[]") String[] myParams){
    ....
}
```

That works for example for forms like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myParam[]" value="myVal1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myParam[]" value="myVal2" />
```

This is the simplest solution :)

Comment: does that preserve the order?

Comment: I was able to use just the name rather than the [] in Spring 3.0 thusly: @RequestParam(value="myParam") String[] myParams

Comment: I do not share the findings of @MSmith, though.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain `List<String>` through this. Also is it possible to obtain a java bean like `List<MyBean>`

Comment: I think you can remove the brackets from param name.

Comment: Works without brackets, but they may be needed if you use jQuery to push each selected checkbox into array and send it as param.

Comment: With jQuery, I found that sending it as a comma separated string seemed to work: `var array = '1,5,33';`

Comment: It does not work with this kind of url: `&order[0][column]=1&order[0][dir]=desc`?

Comment: Using `myParam[]` saved me. Using just `myParam` didn't work.

Comment: I used '@RequestParam(value = "ot-replace[]") String[] otReplace' but still getting Invalid character found in the request target

Answer (score 39):

Subscribing what basil said in a comment to the question itself, if `method = RequestMethod.GET` you can use `@RequestParam List<String> groupVal`.

Then calling the service with the list of params is as simple as:

```
API_URL?groupVal=kkk,ccc,mmm
```

Comment: I have a small problem. What should i do if one of the string element contains ','  and the url decodes this as two separated string element.

Comment: @Jimmylau You have to escape the string. "," can be escaped with "%2C".

Answer (score 25):

Just complementing what Donal Fellows said, you can use List with @RequestParam

```
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam(value="myParam") List<ObjectToParse> myParam){
....
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

One way you could accomplish this (in a hackish way) is to create a wrapper class for the `List`. Like this:

```
class ListWrapper {
     List<String> myList; 
     // getters and setters
}
```

Then your controller method signature would look like this:

```
public String controllerMethod(ListWrapper wrapper) {
    ....
}
```

No need to use the `@RequestParam` or `@ModelAttribute` annotation if the collection name you pass in the request matches the collection field name of the wrapper class, in my example your request parameters should look like this:

```
myList[0]     : 'myValue1'
myList[1]     : 'myValue2'
myList[2]     : 'myValue3'
otherParam    : 'otherValue'
anotherParam  : 'anotherValue'
```

Comment: Well this is almost the same as using @ModelAttribute, the only difference is that the param is not annotated. I wanted to avoid @ModelAttribute just because I didn't want to create a wrapper. I read somewhere in stackoverflow (I can't remember where exactly) that if you add a param in the controller method without @ModelAttribute annotation (and it wasn't a special object like HttpRequest, HttpResponse...) the framework treat it as if it were annotated with @ModelAttribute. So if that was true this is exactly as having @ModelAttribute. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @driangle
I have a similar case but I have 2 Sets of <Strings> and I wrap them both in one object. However after I do it I can no longer use comma separated syntax to assign values to my sets. If I do ?idsType1=QWE,RTY,UIO I am getting one element with "QWE,RTY,UIO" as value. SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE, Java 8 openjdk

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't obvious to me that although you can accept a Collection as a request param, but on the consumer side **you still have to pass in the collection items as comma separated values**.

For example if the server side api looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/post-topics")
public void handleSubscriptions(@RequestParam("topics") Collection<String> topicStrings) {

    topicStrings.forEach(topic -> System.out.println(topic));
}
```

Directly passing in a collection to the RestTemplate as a RequestParam like **below will result in data corruption**

```
public void subscribeToTopics() {

    List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("first-topic", "second-topic", "third-topic");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:8088/post-topics?topics={topics}",
            null,
            ResponseEntity.class,
            topics);
}
```

Instead you can use

```
public void subscribeToTopics() {

    List<String> topicStrings = Arrays.asList("first-topic", "second-topic", "third-topic");
    String topics = String.join(",",topicStrings);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:8088/post-topics?topics={topics}",
            null,
            ResponseEntity.class,
            topics);
}
```

[The complete example can be found here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15715), hope it saves someone the headache :)

Answer (score -10):

Change hidden field value with checkbox toggle like below...

**HTML:**

```
<input type='hidden' value='Unchecked' id="deleteAll" name='anyName'>
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="toggle(this)"/> Delete All
```

**Script:**

```
function toggle(obj) {`var $input = $(obj);
    if ($input.prop('checked')) {

    $('#deleteAll').attr( 'value','Checked');

    } else {

    $('#deleteAll').attr( 'value','Unchecked');

    }

}
```

Comment: Was this attempting to answer the OP at all ? Doesn't seem related.