# Spring 3 MVC jQuery POST submit variable number of data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In the client side, I am using jQuery to submit a number of  pairs to the server.

**But the number of entries is variable.**

For example:

```
1: 1.55
2: 2.33
3: 5.66
```

In the server side, how should I design the Controller so that it could take the POST data and store it in a List / Map?

Something like:

```
@RequestMapping ("/submitdata")
public @ResponseBody String changeData (???) {
// changes to database
return "Success";
}
```

EDIT:

I got the answer:

```
@RequestMapping ("/submitdata")
public @ResponseBody String changeData (@RequestParam Map <String, String> params) {

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: params.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println ("Key = " + entry.getKey() + " Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }

// changes to database
return "Success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @RequestParam annotation to grab POST data

Comment: sorry i did not mention that the number of entries is variable

Comment: May this link answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596351/binding-a-list-in-requestparam

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`@ResponseBody Map<String,String> udpateIdentification(HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("jspObject") Test test,BindingResult result)`

The values will be get bind to the ModelAttribute if you have used that in your JSP