# How to send array with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest

How do I send array parameter with Spring RestTemplate?

This is the server side implementation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/train", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public TrainResponse train(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, 
    @RequestParam String category,
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "positiveDocId[]") String[] positiveDocId,
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "negativeDocId[]") String[] negativeDocId) 
{
    ...
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("category", parameters.getName());
map.put("positiveDocId[]", positiveDocs); // positiveDocs is String array
map.put("negativeDocId[]", negativeDocs); // negativeDocs is String array
TrainResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/admin/train?category={category}&positiveDocId[]={positiveDocId[]}&negativeDocId[]={negativeDocId[]}", TrainResponse.class, map);
```

The following is the actual request URL which is obviously incorrect:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/train?category=spam&positiveDocId%5B%5D=%5BLjava.lang.String;@4df2868&negativeDocId%5B%5D=%5BLjava.lang.String;@56d5c657`
```

Have been trying to search around but couldn't find a solution. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring's UriComponentsBuilder does the trick and allows also for Variable expansion. Assuming that you want to pass an array of strings as param "attr" to a resource for which you only have a URI with path variable:

```
UriComponents comp = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(
    "http:/www.example.com/widgets/{widgetId}").queryParam("attr", "width", 
        "height").build();
UriComponents expanded = comp.expand(12);
assertEquals("http:/www.example.com/widgets/12?attr=width&attr=height", 
   expanded.toString());
```

Otherwise, if you need to define a URI that is supposed to be expanded at runtime, and you do not know the size of the array in advance, use an https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570 UriTemplate with {?key*} placeholder and expand it with the UriTemplate class from  https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates.

```
UriTemplate template = UriTemplate.fromTemplate(
    "http://example.com/widgets/{widgetId}{?attr*}");
template.set("attr", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
String expanded = template.expand();
assertEquals("http://example.com/widgets/?attr=1&attr=2&attr=3", 
    expanded);
```

For languages other than Java see https://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/wiki/Implementations.

Comment: UriComponentsBuilder.queryParam() has an overload which accepts a collection, so you don't need to add a dependency for UriTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up constructing the URL by looping through the collection.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("category", parameters.getName());

String url = "http://localhost:8080/admin/train?category={category}";
if (positiveDocs != null && positiveDocs.size() > 0) {
    for (String id : positiveDocs) {
        url += "&positiveDocId[]=" + id;
    }
}
if (negativeDocId != null && negativeDocId.size() > 0) {
    for (String id : negativeDocId) {
        url += "&negativeDocId[]=" + id;
    }
}

TrainResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, TrainResponse.class, map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've achieved it:

The REST Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Response> getPublicationSkus(
       @RequestParam(value = "skus[]", required = true) List<String> skus) {
    ...
}
```

The request:

```
List<String> skus = Arrays.asList("123","456","789");

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("skus", toPlainString(skus));

Response response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/test?skus[]={skus}", 
                                      Response.class, params);
```

Then you just need to implement a method that converts the `List` or the `String[]` to a plain string separated by commas, for example in `Java 8` would be something like this:

```
private static String toPlainString(List<String> skus) {
    return skus.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change your request mapping from

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/train", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/train/{category}/{positiveDocId[]}/{negativeDocId[]}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and your URL in restTemplate

change URl in the below given format

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/train/category/1,2,3,4,5/6,7,8,9
```