# Save multiple row from jsp in one entity at a time(springMVC-hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I need a help. may be very noob question for experienced programmer. :)
I have a entity like this...

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    getters and setters...
}
```

and a jsp form like this

```
<form>
    Enter your country name:<input type="text" name="myCountryName" /><br>
    Enter your friend county name: <input type="text" name="frndCountryName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

(input name is dummy )
(actually this input fields will be created dynamically and the name also will be dynamic. So i don't know , how many input box will be there. )
Now how can i save this two country name in one domain with two different column in database with two different id?
Please help if you can.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to save it now? Are you using some controller? You can get POST data from form using `@RequestParam` and manually create and fill two entities.

Comment: actually this input fields will be created dynamically and the name also will be dynamic. So i don't know , how many input box will be there. Is it possible to solve this with @RequestParam ??

Comment: You may be interested in answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/5624006/816456