# How to set default value to get array parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a search method and it has keywords parameter. What I want to do is set a default value(empty String array) to keywords parameter. Is there any way to do this?

```
@GetMapping(value = "search")
public List<Integer> search(@RequestParam String[] keywords){
 return calculate(Arrays.asList(keyword));
}
```

Comment: did you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596351/binding-a-list-in-requestparam exactly this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624006/5558072

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below:

```
@RequestParam(value="keywords[]", required=false) String[] keywords
```

or

```
 @RequestParam(value=" ", required=false) String[] keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` has an attribute `defaultValue` to set default value.

```
public List<Integer> search(@RequestParam(defaultValue="default value") String[] keywords){
 return calculate(Arrays.asList(keyword));
}
```