# How to get an array of objects with spring @RequestParam in ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: spring, data-binding, collections, get, request

I have an entity Movies and an entity Genres in a relationship many to many.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "movies_genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movies_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genres_id"))
private Set<Genres> genresSet = new HashSet<>();
```

In a rest controller class, I want to do this:

```
@GetMapping("/search-movies")
public Iterable<Movies> search(
    @RequestParam(value = "genresSet", required = false) Set<Genres> genresSet,
    @RequestParam(value = "synopsis", required = false) String synopsis,
    @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
    @RequestParam(value = "runtime", required = false) Integer runtime
)
```

I use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) on front-end to send params to the back-end and `genresSet` is array of objects, for example

```js
[
    { id: 1, name: 'action'},
    { id: 2, name: 'crime'},
    { id: 3, name: 'comedy'}
]
```

I thought that Spring would automatically convert array of objects into set of genres, but it gives me null.

How to get values of genres in form of a set of values?

To recap, the user enters more than one genre, where each genre is represented as an object, so front-end sends array of genre objects and back-end needs to bind that array to the set of genres, where set of genres is a many to many property of Movie entity.

Comment: Could you show us `Genres` object source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942193/spring-mvc-complex-object-as-get-requestparam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rethink your parameters and change `Set<Genres>` either to `Set<Integer>` or `Set<String>`. Because you need just ids or just names of genres to use them in search query, you don't need to pass the whole Genres object.

```
@GetMapping("/search-movies")
public Iterable<Movies> search(
    @RequestParam(value = "genresIds", required = false) Set<Long> genresIds,
    // ... other parameters without changes
```

would accept

```
"genresIds": [1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/search-movies")
public Iterable<Movies> search(
    @RequestParam(value = "genresNames", required = false) Set<String> genresNames,
    // ... other parameters without changes
```

would accept

```
"genresNames": ['action', 'crime', 'comedy']
```

Comment: I like the `Set<Long> genresIds` approach. 

I used this to extract id values from array of objects: `genresIds: genresSet.map(a => a.id)` and I get 1, 2, 3.

To avoid null on a back-end, it is vital to put square brackets after genresIds in value parameter, like this: `@RequestParam(value = "genresIds[]", required = false) Set<Long> genresIds`.

With this, it is a complete answer for me. Thanks @naXa

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could accomplish this is to create a wrapper class for the `Set`. For example:

```
public class GenresWrapper {
    Set<Genres> genresSet; 
    // ... accessors
}
```

Then your controller method would look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/search-movies")
public Iterable<Movies> search(
        @ModelAttribute GenresWrapper genres,
        // ... other parameters
)
```

Or you could wrap all the request parameters in a single wrapper object.

<sup>This answer is based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618909/1429387).</sup>