# Filter object from list based on property value spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a rest service that will return `List` of objects

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private String state;
}
```

Now, I need to filter object from list based on fields provided on rest call:

```
http://localhost:8080/myuri?state=NY
```

Now, I need to develop custom filter and I did only find [property filter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/PropertyFilter.html) not something like I want. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: You want to filter your response from the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `Jackson` to do this. Just filter it using `Stream API`. If data, are loaded from `DB`, filter it using `SQL`'s `WHERE` clause.

Example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/states", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyObject> loadStates(@RequestParam(name = "state", defaultValue = "NY", required = false) String[] states) {
    return service.loadAndFilterByState(states);
}
```

If you have a cached list, you can filter it like below:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/states", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<MyObject> loadStates(@RequestParam(name = "state", defaultValue = "NY", required = false) String[] states) {
    Arrays.sort(states);
    return getStates()
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> Arrays.binarySearch(states, s.getState()) > -1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

See also:

- [Binding a list in @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596351/binding-a-list-in-requestparam)

Comment: state could be 0 to many so i was looking something other than java 8 way.

Comment: @user9735824, what do you mean by `0 to many`? Could you give me some examples? How do you store states list?

Comment: so uri could be `http://localhost:8080/myuri` or `http://localhost:8080/myuri?state=NY&state=CA&state=PA`

Comment: @user9735824, OK, I understand now. How do you store states in your app. Just in `List`? Or do you have `DB` or another store for them?

Comment: @user9735824, I updated my answer with example how multiple values can be handled. Could you please specify what you would like to use instead of `Java 8` `Stream API`?