# Jackson doesn't deserialize list field in Kotlin data class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I'm building a simple Spring Boot service with Kotlin. I have an endpoint

```
@GetMapping("/summary")
fun getLoginReport(params: SummaryRequest): ResponseEntity<LoginSummaryResponse> { 
// not important
}
```

The `SummaryRequest` class is defined like

```
data class SummaryRequest(
    val groupBy: List<SummaryGroupBy>
)
```

`SummaryGroupBy` is an enum class. If I make a request passing a single groupBy parameter (`/summary?groupBy=region`), the data class object is built successfully. But if I pass several groupBy (`/summary/groupBy=region,date`), I get the following error:

```
[Field error in object 'SummaryRequest' on field 'groupBy': rejected value [region,date]; codes [typeMismatch.SummaryRequest.groupBy,typeMismatch.groupBy,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [SummaryRequest.groupBy,groupBy]; arguments []; default message [groupBy]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [api.domain.SummaryGroupBy] for value 'region,date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant api.domain.SummaryGroupBy.REGION,DATE]]
```

But, the funny part is it works if I change `SummaryRequest` to a regular class (like below). So, I'm puzzled about why it doesn't work with data classes.

```
class SummaryRequest {
    var groupBy: List<SummaryGroupBy> = ArrayList
}
```

I have `jackson-module-kotlin` as a dependency.
Why Jackson cannot deserialize a list in a data class?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: update your JSON request payload

Comment: This might help, see [Binding a list in @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596455/1246282)