# How to use @Pathvariable and @RequestParam at the same request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying this code:

Request URL: GET: /produtName/v1/00000000123?model=1,2

```
@GetMapping(value="/{product}/{version}/{document}?model={model}) 
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(
            @PathVariable("product") String product,    
            @PathVariable("version") String version, 
            @PathVariable("document") String document,
            @RequestParam("model") List<String> model) {
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `?model={model}` part. It is not needed. If you leave it in the path you won't be able to call this API method.

Also i'm not sure if you can bind a `@RequestParam` to a list. You should use [`@MatrixVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-matrix-variables) for that.

EDIT: According to the answerers in the SO thread [Binding a list in @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596351/binding-a-list-in-requestparam) it is possible to use `List` with `@RequestParam`. It can be worthwhile to take a look at those answers as well.

Comment: Thanks! @Maurice

Comment: @Aline please also check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596351/binding-a-list-in-requestparam) about binding a list in requestparam. According to the answerers it is possible to bind a list to requestparam.

Comment: @Maurice, I think if you try to use `@MatrixVariable` it won't work, because spring has by default disabled the semicolon separation. You might need to follow this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-matrix-variables#configuration

Comment: @stergipe you can use `@MatrixVariable` with comma as well.